# How to install mesh in google colab

Tags: python-2.7, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install this mesh processing library in google colab following the steps in the repo https://github.com/MPI-IS/mesh

```
apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

and

```
make
make install
```

but when I run one of the depending projects https://github.com/TimoBolkart/voca
 I get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/voca/run_voca.py", line 22, in <module>
    from utils.inference import inference
  File "/content/voca/utils/inference.py", line 27, in <module>
    from psbody.mesh import Mesh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psbody'
```

what is the proper way to install this library in colab?

Answer (score 3):

Currently this works in google colab too

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/MPI-IS/mesh.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I solved:

```
#install boost library
!sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
#boost-root or boost-include-directory may be here /usr/include/boost
####follow below with example
"""Consider your installing mesh from https://github.com/MPI-IS/mesh, it has 
makefile(filename:makefile)"""
#--Cloning repository
!git clone https://github.com/MPI-IS/mesh.git 
#--Providing permission to admin rights
!chmod 755 /content/mesh/Makefile
#--move to its project root directory by the following command
%cd /content/mesh
#--run following from mesh-docs for compiling and installing make file
!BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/boost make all
```